# Cauchy Schwarz inequality for random vectors: need help with the proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I have a question related to the proof of Cauchy Schwarz inequality (for discrete random variables).

We have two random discrete variables $X,Y$ and we know that $\mathbb E[X^2] \text{ and } \mathbb E[Y^2]$ converges (clearly if converges, then absolutely).

I create a new variable $Y-aX$, where $a \in \mathbb R$.

Then the proof proceeds by considering $\mathbb E[(Y-aX)^2]=\mathbb E[Y^2+(aX)^2-2aXY]=\mathbb E[Y^2]+\mathbb E[(aX)^2]-\mathbb E[2aXY]$

To do the last step, should not I be sure that $\mathbb E[YX]$ is a convergent series? And if yes, how can I be sure about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should first make sure that $\mathbb{E}[\vert XY\vert]$ is finite. This follows from the inequality
$$\vert XY\vert\leq \frac{X^2+Y^2}{2},$$
which follows from $(\vert X\vert -\vert Y\vert)^2\geq 0$.